# Geometric Shape Recognition & Find Extreme Points in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, shapes

Can anyone tell me how to recognize geometric shape using C#?

I have geometric shapes like triangle, hexagon, pentagon, diamond, square,parallelogram, rectangle, etc.
I have drawn all these shapes using mspaint.

i have one picture box, using opendialog i am selecting any of the geometric shapes, into picturebox.
I want to identify the shape of the image & extreme points. As it is hand made image, i want to draw a proper image using extreme points.

If anyone has some code or some references, then please send it to me...

I need it very very urgently.

Thanks,
Riya

Comment: Urgent you say? I'm probably already too late then, a shame.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a neural network http://www.generation5.org/content/2004/aiSomPic.asp

or Hough Transform http://www.generation5.org/content/2008/houghTransform.asp

Answer (score 0):

Or you could look into [edge detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection) and/or [vectorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(computer_graphics)). Good luck!